# Scrapy closes suddenly on big list of urls

Tags: scrapy

Let me describe the flow of my spider: 
First I provide around 300 urls. 
Scrapy starts crawling the first 10 urls (is 10 configurable?) 
Then for each url, there are 2 actions:

- First Action: Spider goes to all items listed on the page (48 items).

  - For each item, I crawl all the paginations. It can go up to 50 or more of the feedback of the item and store them in Postgres.
- Second Action: Spider fetches the next page and does the same routine again

The Depth for my Scrapy is 20, so if we do some calculations, the total number of pages crawled should be:

**300*20*48*50 = 14 400 000** pages in one crawl. 
Is this something Scrapy is capable of? 
My server is 8Gb of RAM

Now what happens is that Scrapy gets lost with the first 10 urls and never goes beyond that. Do you guys know why would that happen?

Comment: does your scrapy process gets killed? maybe your ram is maxed out

Comment: There is not limit on the amount of pages crawled by scrapy. Could you show the logs so we can know what is causing your spider to die?

Comment: As Umair has pointed out you're most likely running out of memory. You could either be loading up to many requests/objects or you have a memory leak in your code. Could you share your spider code and `settings.py`? also take a look at https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html